# MVC Multithreaded server with entity framework object creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a POST action on my API that calls this function on an entity:

```
    Public Async Function MarkAsSeenBy(db As TaplomaV2Entities, user As User, Optional markAsComplete As Boolean = False, Optional save As Boolean = True) As Threading.Tasks.Task

    Dim userContent = Me.UserContents.SingleOrDefault(Function(uc) uc.UserID = user.UserID)

    If userContent Is Nothing Then

        userContent = New UserContent() With {
            .UserID = user.UserID,
            .FirstViewed = DateTime.Now,
            .LastViewed = DateTime.Now,
            .CourseContentID = Me.CourseContentID,
            .ViewCount = 1
        }

        If markAsComplete Then
            userContent.TimeCompleted = DateTime.Now
        End If

        db.UserContents.Add(userContent)

    Else

        userContent.ViewCount += 1
        userContent.LastViewed = DateTime.Now

        If markAsComplete Then
            userContent.TimeCompleted = If(userContent.TimeCompleted, DateTime.Now)
        End If

        db.Entry(userContent).State = EntityState.Modified

    End If

    If save Then
        Await db.SaveChangesAsync()
    End If

End Function
```

Essentially it checks if it has a UserContent record associated with it, if not then it creates one and then increments the seen count and the time and so forth.

Is this likely to create multiple records in the DB if the endpoint is called more than once?

Since the server is threaded I would expect it to start checking on two different threads, both find no record and so both add a record which makes two records.

What's the correct way to combat this kind of race condition with Entity Framework when creating new objects based on DB conditions?

Comment: Always start with the docs: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I was aware of how to deal with concurrency with existing entities but my case involves creating a new entity.